# Drop a specific packet on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, udp

I am looking for a way to drop a specific packet received on Windows. Preferably on both Windows 7 and 10. In my case I want to block a igmp v2 membership report on a UDP connection that I have information about.

I have a limited knowledge on networking and is mostly wondering which direction is the best to solve such an issue.

To my knowledge Windows lacks this support with the Windows firewall. Surely there has to be an already existing software, a go-to application people know of with distributable licenses, that can solve this? I've read that making a WFP callout driver seem to be able to solve the issue but that seem a bit excessive or is that quite simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is clearly difficult to do this with existing software. I tried several but my conclusion is that the only way to solve this is by making a driver. I used the framework WinDivert to help out. This driver then has to be digitally signed. All in all, this is a quite annoying issue to be stuck with in the first place.